# How to efficiently create a list of lists by putting an element at every possible index available in Java using LinkedLists?

Tags: java, doubly-linked-list, listiterator

Assume I have the following list in Java: `List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));`

Now, let's say that I want to create a list of lists representing insertion of the integer 0 at every index available in `list`. That is, I want to create a list represented by:

`[[0, 1, 2, 3], [1, 0, 2, 3], [1, 2, 0, 3], [1, 2, 3, 0]]`

My question is whether there is a way to do this efficiently?

For example, we could do the following:

```
List<List<Integer>> lists = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i <= list.size(); i ++) {
    List<Integer> newList = new LinkedList<>(list);
    newList.add(i, 0);
    lists.add(newList);
}
```

In this case, each iteration creation of the original list copy is in `O(n)` and adding the element at the specified index `i` is also `O(n)` (unless the beginning or end since we are working with a LinkedList).

I am wondering whether there is a possibility of using a `ListIterator` to mitigate the latter time overhead. That is, iterating over the original list via a `ListIterator`, adding the element `0` (`O(1)`), then creating a new list from it (`O(n)`), and then removing it from the original list (`O(1)`).

And, if this is possible, assuming our list is huge, would this be a good improvement? Or would this solution be overly pedantic, since overall each iteration is `O(n)` anyway.

EDIT: So, it seems like I can achieve my solution with the following:

```
List<List<Integer>> lists = new ArrayList<>();
ListIterator(Integer> lt = list.listIterator();
while (lt.hasNext()) {
    lt.add(0);
    lists.add(new ArrayList<>(list));
    lt.previous();
    lt.remove();
    lt.next();
}
lt.add(0);
lists.add(list);
```

But is the runtime really better for very large lists? I am not sure.

Comment: If the substituted lists are immutable and you have to do this a lot, I’d make a custom ArrayList subclass and iterator that provides a _view_ containing the zeros without creating any extra lists.

Comment: I agree, that makes much more sense. But I am very curious what the most efficient way of creating actual extra lists would be even though in reality this would be extremely impractical.